# Recommendation for RF simulation software that can do animations of wave motion through the model

Tags: microwave, comsol

I am trying to get an intuitive visual spacial understanding of the behaviour of RF electromagnetism though different shapes and materials.

Being able to visualise the wave motion is really helpful. I learnt a lot form [this simple 2D wave tank applet](https://www.falstad.com/ripple/) It is possible use it to get an understanding of various antenna types.

I would now like to learn about how microwave frequencies propagate through microstrip, distributed element filters and patch antennas. Is there software that can animate wave motion though these kind of models? My boss has Ansys which can probably do this, but it seems like the set up time using Ansys for a simple model is long and complicated. Perhaps there is something in between the complexity of the wave tank applet and Ansys that will do what I want.

Comment: Site rules: *Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are off-topic as they are rarely useful to others and quickly obsolete. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.*

Comment: You are looking for “time domain finite element” simulators. The set up time for an electromagnetic simulation is likely to be long for most simulators.